# Ruby http/get cookie formating

Tags: ruby, cookies

Via my code i get cookie via get request:

```
http = Net::HTTP.new('kdfgdfgdfglat.gsdfsdo', 443)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
path = '/gfgdfgdfgfdgdfg'
resp, data = http.get(path, {'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0', "Cookie" => "dfgdfgdfg=17"})

cookie = resp.response['set-cookie']
```

Cookie's are such:

```
ASP.NET_SessionId=mnxjnm140qvvt4wvlfielud3; domain=.e-dfgdfgdfg.godfgdfgv.pl; path=/; secure; HttpOnly, TSe20548=a4ad9705817edcebbdf2e0c3f869b10843e5bb63617303a3523b64a0; Path=/, TS7848cb=98330ff418e3c9a3b2afb5f10398363043e5bb63617303a3523b64a036af3f5e7cfaddf8; path=/; domain=.e-dfgfdgdfgf.godfgdfggv.pdfgdfl, TSe20548_31=88ba62b4efd7e40ff9fa891b1764eb6e43e5bb63617303a3000000000000000000e1d4e1bdb727a5ac9c00848b7c7c770a3b491a57; Path=/
```

But as you can see, i have ASP.NET_SessionId, TSe20548_31 etc (also 20548 is dynamic, and numbers could be other).

My question is how to clear and format cookies, to such view:

`ASP.NET_SessionId=mnxjnm140qvvt4wvlfielud3;` `TSe20548=a4ad9705817edcebbdf2e0c3f869b10843e5bb63617303a3523b64a0; TS7848cb=98330ff418e3c9a3b2afb5f10398363043e5bb63617303a3523b64a036af3f5e7cfaddf8; TSe20548_31=88ba62b4efd7e40ff9fa891b1764eb6e43e5bb63617303a3000000000000000000e1d4e1bdb727a5ac9c00848b7c7c770a3b491a57;`

As you can see, i must get only cookie and it's value, without path, and other extra information. How could i do this? And is this real? How to delete some data from cookie? So i need to leave ASP.NET_SessionId and it's value, and TS*** and those values. How could i do it?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev i need this, becouse i need) secret information ahah) just need for sending headers... And need so as describe below

Comment: @SergioTulentsev so how could i do this?

Comment: I still don't quite get what you want.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev look: cookie contain such data: name=newvalue; expires=date; path=/; domain=.example.org.  but i must select only names, and it's values, without any path, etc

Comment: @SergioTulentsev now did you understand?

Comment: Nope. Where are those cookies, how do you get them, why is there asp.net mentioned?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37737/discussion-between-sergio-tulentsev-and-valdis-azamaris)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really not that difficult. Just split on semicolon and filter. Or scan the string for the pairs that interest you. Something like this:

```
s1 = "ASP.NET_SessionId=mnxjnm140qvvt4wvlfielud3; domain=.e-konsulat.gov.pl; path=/; secure; HttpOnly, TSe20548=a4ad9705817edcebbdf2e0c3f869b10843e5bb63617303a3523b64a0; Path=/, TS7848cb=98330ff418e3c9a3b2afb5f10398363043e5bb63617303a3523b64a036af3f5e7cfaddf8; path=/; domain=.e-konsulat.gov.pl, TSe20548_31=88ba62b4efd7e40ff9fa891b1764eb6e43e5bb63617303a3000000000000000000e1d4e1bdb727a5ac9c00848b7c7c770a3b491a57; Path=/ "

regex = /(?<key>(ASP\.NET_SessionId|TS\w+)=[^;]+)/

a1 = s1.scan(regex).flatten # => ["ASP.NET_SessionId=mnxjnm140qvvt4wvlfielud3", "TSe20548=a4ad9705817edcebbdf2e0c3f869b10843e5bb63617303a3523b64a0", "TS7848cb=98330ff418e3c9a3b2afb5f10398363043e5bb63617303a3523b64a036af3f5e7cfaddf8", "TSe20548_31=88ba62b4efd7e40ff9fa891b1764eb6e43e5bb63617303a3000000000000000000e1d4e1bdb727a5ac9c00848b7c7c770a3b491a57"]
a2 = a1.map{|s| s.split('=')} # => [["ASP.NET_SessionId", "mnxjnm140qvvt4wvlfielud3"], ["TSe20548", "a4ad9705817edcebbdf2e0c3f869b10843e5bb63617303a3523b64a0"], ["TS7848cb", "98330ff418e3c9a3b2afb5f10398363043e5bb63617303a3523b64a036af3f5e7cfaddf8"], ["TSe20548_31", "88ba62b4efd7e40ff9fa891b1764eb6e43e5bb63617303a3000000000000000000e1d4e1bdb727a5ac9c00848b7c7c770a3b491a57"]]
h1 = Hash[a2] # => {"ASP.NET_SessionId"=>"mnxjnm140qvvt4wvlfielud3", "TSe20548"=>"a4ad9705817edcebbdf2e0c3f869b10843e5bb63617303a3523b64a0", "TS7848cb"=>"98330ff418e3c9a3b2afb5f10398363043e5bb63617303a3523b64a036af3f5e7cfaddf8", "TSe20548_31"=>"88ba62b4efd7e40ff9fa891b1764eb6e43e5bb63617303a3000000000000000000e1d4e1bdb727a5ac9c00848b7c7c770a3b491a57"}
```